# FontAwesome: What is going wrong?

Tags: html, css

For some reasons the icons don't work for me from FrontAwesome.
Running on chrome.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

</head>
<body>
    <i class="icon major fa-paper-plane"></i>
    <p>test?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answers are not helping you. The basic question would be: Are you working in a local .html file? If so, you cannot use `//maxcdn..`. In Windows for example, the browser starts looking for `file:////maxcdn..`.

Instead, use `https://maxcdn` so the browser starts looking online instead of the local file system.

So your HTML will look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
    <p>test?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You omitted `fa` in the class name
2. The CDN link should begin with `//`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

```
<i class="icon major fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
```

That should display the icon. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvf835ws/)

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
```

Comment: My CSS is completely empty. Just setting up all my files.

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="icon major fa-paper-plane"></i>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <i class="fa fa-paper-plane icon major"></i> <!-- add class fa-->
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-paper-plane icon major"></i>
```

Comment: @LarsBeute link site?

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when you are serving the html pages from your computer without any help of server . I had seen something like that before. So I would request you to please put your code directory in a server or like local installation of apache or nginx . 
Or , For quick response processing time use [HTTP-SERVER](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

This is a quite fast and reliable server that can serve page contents easily .
. And after that access your codes and pages with localhost or server ports . and thus server will request the sources from the CDN quickly.